# Feature Request: [Broken external links]

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, external-links, broken-link

I was looking for a solution to a problem related to rendering a JSON file in HTML. I searched on Stack Overflow and found the answer to a similar question referring me to another question which was good.

After seeing the new question, it was also the same problem being solved, but the problem was the external link provided, as the answer is no longer available leaving that question still not answered for future reference.

I was wondering if there is a way or a new feature to make SO users add a little gist of the external link so if it is not available the solution could still be relevant?

Comment: If the answer _only_ contains the link and provides no meaningful information to go off then you can flag the answer as "Not an answer", otherwise you're able to downvote it if you found it unhelpful (once you have the reputation required to downvote).

Comment: And, FYI, this is why answers are not supposed to require externally linked material in order to be understood.  External links get go bad or the content in them changes all the time.  One should not be linking to a gist for code required to understand answers.  One should be including the code for the answer in the question itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 I suspect that the OP is using "gist" in its original sense, rather than referring to a Github Gist.

Comment: There's a classic MSE post on this topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/334566 When you see links like that on new answers, ask the author to add some context so the link can be fixed if it becomes invalid, and ask them to copy the important info from the link into their answer. Or consider editing in that info yourself.

Comment: It is partly incomprehensible near *"leaving that question still not answer for future reference"*. You may consider [fixing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/417821/edit) it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I made an update to the question but I guess Nick stands with Ukraine 's comment had provided a solution to dealing with such answers